# In Dash Python: How to access a frame from a video feed in a callback function

Tags: python, flask, callback, video-streaming, plotly-dash

In Dash, I am trying to access a frame from a video feed in an `@app.callback` function.

My badly working approach was to call the camera object separately once for the video feed returned as a generator and a second time for the selected frames within the `@app.callback` function with an refresh `dcc.Interval`. (The code actually breaks when the interval is smaller than 200 or the code is running for longer periods)

Is there any cleverer solution for this?

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from flask import Flask, Response

import cv2
import base64


colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)


camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def video_generator(camera):
    while True:
        success, image = camera.read()
        if not success:
            print("video camera could not connect")
            break
        else: 
            ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
            frame = jpeg.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

def photo_generator(camera):
    success, frame = camera.read()  # read the camera frame
    if not success:
        print("photo camera could not connect")
        pass
    else:
        return frame


@server.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(video_generator(camera),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.H4("Webcam"),
        html.Img(src="/video_feed")
    ], style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding-left': '25px', 'vertical-align': 'top'}),
    html.Div([
        html.H4("Snapshot"),
        dcc.Interval( 
            id = 'graph-update', 
            interval = 1000, 
            n_intervals = 0
        ),
        html.Img(id="image", src=app.get_asset_url('test_0.png'))
    ], style={'display': 'inline-block', 'width': '49%', 'padding-right': '0px', 'vertical-align': 'top'})
], style={'backgroundColor': colors['background']})


@app.callback(
               Output('image', 'src'),
               Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')
             )
def update_snapshot(n):
    frame = photo_generator(camera)    
    _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.png', frame)
    source_image = base64.b64encode(buffer).decode('utf-8')
    return 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(source_image)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```